# Codeception/WebDriver file upload error: "Invalid Command Method"

Tags: php, webdriver, phantomjs, automated-tests, codeception

I have WebDriver running with PhantomJS, testing a form. There's a file upload input, which looks like:

```
<input id="file_upload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
```

The code I'm using to test the input is:

```
$I->attachFile('#file_upload', 'sample_upload.png');
```

However, codeception returns this:

```
Invalid Command Method - {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json"...
```

Along with a list of the response information. Is this a common issue?
I'm using [jquery-fileupload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for the input, but I've also tried the test after disabling this.

Comment: exactly same error here, did you found the fix?